# What is the meaning of ですだ? 「こちらですだ」

Tags: dialects

> こちらですだ

This sentence is from Mirai Nikki episode 4. The character speaks some kind of dialect. The context is that she is showing the way to the protagonists.

I don't understand the meaning of だ here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than meaning anything, it indicates the character is speaking in a stereotypical rural language. There is a famous(?) old song [俺ら東京さ行ぐだ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%BA%E3%82%89%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E3%81%95%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%90%E3%81%A0). The singer is from Aomori, which is in Tohoku, where the dialect typically uses だべ ending.

In terms of meaning, it is the same as こちらです.